# Jetstream en Laravel Sail

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-jetstream, jetstream

soy nuevo en Laravel, estoy usando Docker con Laravel Sail para realizar proyectos. Tengo una duda respecto de Jetstream.
Si quiero usar Jetstream sin Docker, lo invoco al crear el proyecto (*laravel new xxxxxx --jet*).
En cambio, cuando creo un nuevo proyecto de Laravel Sail en Docker en la consola de Ubuntu, la indicación es: *curl -s https://laravel.build/NombreDelProyecto | bash*
En que momento invoco a Jetstream, cómo lo hago?

Desde ya, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los comandos que muestras son para instalar un proyecto.

1. Con el instalador de laravel (es un paquete PHP, tu máquina local debe tener PHP y Composer instalados, asi como un gestor de base de datos y todas las herramientas que el proyecto vaya a usar).

```bash
composer global require laravel/installer
laravel new example-app
```

Y le puedes pasar algunas [opciones](https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/4e77109c557ec680fe87ba45b2585dd41ce18a69/src/NewCommand.php#L51) como `jet`:

```bash
laravel new example-app --jet
```

2. Con sail (tu máquina local debe tener Docker y Docker Compose instalados, pero no tienes que preocuparte por configurar o instalar herramientas de desarrollo, como servidores web, php, composer y bases de datos en tu máquina local).

```bash
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

Este te va a instalar un proyecto laravel *base* en un contenedor docker, y no te da opciones de *starter kits* como el instalador del punto 1. Esta mas orientado los servicios que quieres instalar, como php, mysql, etc.

Entonces con Sail, lo que puedes hacer es instalar un proyecto laravel *base*, y luego instalar con composer (el composer "dockerizado" de sail) los paquetes que le quieras agregar. Por ejemplo Jetstream.

```bash
sail composer require laravel/jetstream
```

Para luego seguir los pasos como se indica en la documentación de [Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/installation.html)

```bash
sail artisan jetstream:install
```

etc.